# Match single input and two database fields

Tags: mysql, input, match

i'm building a search form for a website, with a single input fields (name and lastname) and i need it to match against two database fields (NAME_FIELD and LNAME_FIELD).
Obviously users can type in the name first or the lastname (or only the lastname) as they prefer.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried MyISAM full text search?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax may be off a bit, but you could do something like:

```
WHERE 'name_field' LIKE %'YOUR_INPUT'% OR 'lname_field' LIKE %'YOUR_INPUT'%
```

You can use `= 'YOUR_FIELD'` to match it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user inputs are NULL when not used:

```
select *
    from YourTable
    where NAME_FIELD = coalesce(@name, NAME_FIELD)
        and LNAME_FIELD = coalesce(@lastname, LNAME_FIELD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using prepared statements:

```
WHERE (:name IS NULL OR NAME_FIELD LIKE :name) 
  OR (:lname IS NULL OR LNAME_FIELD LIKE :lname)
```

Have a look at [MyISAM Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), which will lead to much better performance then the `LIKE` operator.